# How to setup JCE_PROVIDER_CLASS in hibernate.cfg.xml

Tags: hibernate, sybase

How do I configure the JCE_PROVIDER_CLASS in the hibernate.xfg.xml?
Tried to configure it as below -

```
<property name="connection.provider_class">com.certicom.ecc.jcae.Certicom</property>
```

However this cannot be cast to  cast to org.hibernate.connection.ConnectionProvider

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved the issue by appending the configurations for JCE_PROVIDER_CLASS to the database url. E.g. The string configuration is inside hibernate.cfg.xml file: `jdbc:sybase:Tds:xyz:1234/DbName?ENCRYPT_PASSWORD=true&amp;JC‌​E_PROVIDER_CLASS=com.certicom.ecc.jcae.Certicom`